# Vuex blocking/freezing on websocket updates

Tags: javascript, vue.js, websocket, vuex

i didn't find a better way to word the title, sorry.

I'm building a table of crypto markets. (Vue/Vuetify v-data-table). Data is kept in a Vuex store.
I'm connecting to the (Laravel/Echo) API via Vue-Native-Websocket

```
Vue.use(VueNativeSock, url, {
  format: 'json',
  store: store,
  connectManually: true,
  reconnection: true,
  reconnectionAttempts: 5,
  reconnectionDelay: 3000,
})
```

After opening the page in question, i'm subscribing to the update method

```
subscribeMarketUpdates() {
        let marketsToSubscribe = []

        const data = this.$store.state.exchange.markets
        const marketKeys = Object.keys(data)

        for (let i = 0; i < marketKeys.length; i++) {
          marketsToSubscribe = marketsToSubscribe.concat(data[marketKeys[i]].map(market => market.name))
        }

        this.$store.dispatch('sendExchangeSocketMessage', {
            "method": "state.subscribe",
            "params": marketsToSubscribe, // <- all currently present markets
            "id": Date.now(),
        })
      },
```

then i get back a `success` message, followed by the requested market update messages (one update message PER MARKET (!) ).
i handle them as follows:

```
SOCKET_ONMESSAGE (state, message)  {

      state.exchangeSocket.message = message

      if (message.method === 'state.update') {
        this.commit('exchange/UPDATE_MARKET_STATE', { params: message.params, BigNumber })
      }
}
```

```
UPDATE_MARKET_STATE(state, payload) {
      console.log('updating market ', params[0])

      let { params, BigNumber } = payload
      let coin = params[0].match(/(^.*)-/)[1]
      let market = params[0].match(/\w+$/)[0]
      let updatedValues = params[1]
      let resultIndex = state.markets[market].findIndex((e) => e.ticker === coin)
      let result = state.markets[market][resultIndex]
      result.amount = new BigNumber(updatedValues.amount).toFixed(8)
      result.change = new BigNumber(updatedValues.change).toFixed(8)
      result.change_pct = new BigNumber(updatedValues.change_pct).toFixed(4)
      result.close = new BigNumber(updatedValues.close).toFixed(8)
      result.high = new BigNumber(updatedValues.high).toFixed(8)
      result.last = new BigNumber(updatedValues.last).toFixed(8)
      result.low = new BigNumber(updatedValues.low).toFixed(8)
      result.open = new BigNumber(updatedValues.open).toFixed(8)
      result.period = updatedValues.period
      result.volume = updatedValues.volume
      state.markets[market][resultIndex] = result
    }
}
```

it kind of works, but i noticed it being painfully slow.
a `console.time` around the `commit` call reveals 400-700ms (!) for each execution.
each line inside `UPDATE_MARKET_STATE` reports 0.02ms though.

at first i thought something was wrong on the backend, but the guy working on that ensured me that all of the messages are sent within a couple of ms. there has to be something here on my end, that i'm not understanding. this is the backend log:

```
[2022-02-24 14:47:38.733082] [29576] [trace]aw_state.c:206(on_timer): send request to 127.0.0.1:1234, cmd: 301, sequence: 2544786, params: ["ETH-BTC", 86400]
[2022-02-24 14:47:38.733096] [29576] [trace]aw_state.c:206(on_timer): send request to 127.0.0.1:1234, cmd: 301, sequence: 2544787, params: ["404-BTC", 86400]
[2022-02-24 14:47:38.733108] [29576] [trace]aw_state.c:206(on_timer): send request to 127.0.0.1:1234, cmd: 301, sequence: 2544788, params: ["2GIVE-BTC", 86400]
[2022-02-24 14:47:38.733121] [29576] [trace]aw_state.c:206(on_timer): send request to 127.0.0.1:1234, cmd: 301, sequence: 2544789, params: ["$PAC-BTC", 86400]
[2022-02-24 14:47:38.733132] [29576] [trace]aw_state.c:206(on_timer): send request to 127.0.0.1:1234, cmd: 301, sequence: 2544790, params: ["1337-BTC", 86400]
```

(note all of the messages being sent nearly instantly)

the table for displaying the data seems to lock up too (i can only scroll the table each second, and it coincides with a console.log i made, so it really seems there is something blocking, even though i can't see anything that could be the culprit).

```
17:36:03.863 actions.js?4221:19 updating market  1337-BTC
17:36:04.646 actions.js?4221:19 updating market  2GIVE-BTC
17:36:05.421 actions.js?4221:19 updating market  2X2-BTC
17:36:06.264 actions.js?4221:19 updating market  404-BTC
17:36:07.030 actions.js?4221:19 updating market  ABJ-BTC
17:36:07.795 actions.js?4221:19 updating market  ACP-BTC
17:36:08.520 actions.js?4221:19 updating market  ADC-BTC
17:36:09.415 actions.js?4221:19 updating market  AERM-BTC
17:36:10.170 actions.js?4221:19 updating market  ALEX-BTC
17:36:10.977 actions.js?4221:19 updating market  AMBER-BTC
```

(note the update being called roughly each second, even though the ws messages are coming in much faster)

so my assumption is: there's something wrong in how i update my vuex store. something is blocking there, but i can't figure out what exactly. i don't see anything there that could possible cause this lock-up.
(i've also tried to handle the updates in an action (and calling the mutation from there) rather than a mutation, the result was the same, so here you see the mutation code)

i hope somebody can spot my error, because i can't :/

thanks for any help